# Segmentation fault c++ with strings array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, bounds

When I run my program, I get the Segmentation Fault error.  I believe it is coming from how I am using the array "string *words" which is privately declared in the class definition.  I use it here in the .cpp file
anyone know what I need to change? 
heres the function I think the problem is in:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(string filename){

    ifstream inF;

    inF.open(filename.c_str());

    if (inF.fail()){
      cerr << "Error opening file" <<endl;
      exit(1);
    }

    inF >> numwords;
    numwords = 3000;
    words = new string(words[numwords]);


    for(int i=0; i <= numwords - 1; i++){
      inF >> words[i];
    }
    inF.close();
  }
```

Comment: `words = new string(words[numwords])` - what is that line supposed to do in your code? What is the purpose of `words[numwords]` on the right-hand side, inside the braces? If you are the author, then I'm sure you should be able to explain why it is written that way.

Comment: What are you implying Andrey? It may just be a simple mistake.

Answer (score 9):

The line:

```
words = new string(words[numwords]);
```

should actually be:

```
words = new string[numwords];
```

Answer (score 4):

You are going to need to learn how to use a debugger. The exact procedure depends on what system you're using. But if you run your code in a debugger, the debugger will stop *on the exact line* where the problem was detected. As you can imagine, this is very helpful for debugging.

Note that the line where the problem was *detected* and the line where the problem *started* may be quite different.